# Insulation and added timbers in attic problem

Tags: insulation, attic-conversion

I have stripped most of the attic (was an unregistered conversion) and the rafters have what seems to be additional timber on them which aligned with the previous wall/roof covering. The timbers impede the straight runs of about 400mm wide by cutting in at the top and bottom but some cut the 400mm wide 'channels' in half and I worry about how much insulation I will lose across the roof span.

Question is, what is my best option, to remove or insulate around? Will be using celotex PIR or similar. I have removed a handful of the 'additional' timber and wasn't concerned until I met 1st fix nails.

[image: inside surface of roof showing additional timber parallel to rafters]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Lge0R49

Comment: You're exposition is confusing. Or maybe I'm just confused. I think that you may be struggling with an old implementation of the [IRC's R806.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.1)

Comment: @popham thanks! That's a really interesting read and has helped a lot. Very much appreciated. Many thanks